# Facebook sharedposts edge return empty list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api v2.10. I want to retrieve the Likes, Comments and SharedPosts of MyPage's posts.
**/likes** and **/comments** edges of graph api are okay. But **/sharedposts** edge return empty list like this.

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

How can I fix it.

Comment: This will only return posts your app is allowed to see. For shares made by user profiles, that means you would need to have user_posts permission from that very user that made the share.

Comment: How to request user_posts permission from user?

Comment: Like any other permission - by implementing Facebook login. (But you do realize this makes little sense, if you don’t know who those users are in the first place, right?)

Comment: If my page doesn't have app, I can't get user_posts permissions, Right?

Comment: If you don’t have an app, you would not be making any API requests in the first place ...